# What's the difference between bootstrap datepicker "setDate" and "update" methd?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried to use

```
$element.datepicker('setDate', dateObj);
```

And

```
$element.datepicker('update', dateObj);
```

to set the internal date of a datepicker. But it looks like if i use setDate, the default selected date(which is the start date) is still highlighted, but update will clear the default selected date and use the new dateObj as selected

I wonder how to clear the default selected date with setDate

Comment: why can't you use the one that works?

Comment: I definitely can, just curious why

Comment: Are you usng this one? https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

Comment: are you sure this is bootstrap? can you post a link to the code you're using?

Comment: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been playing around trying out different alternatives to [the API](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#update) and according to my findings, there's no difference between those two.

```
$("#calendar").datetimepicker("update",new Date());
$("#calendar").datetimepicker("setDate",new Date());
```

It seemed to me confusing and suspicious that they'd put in two different methods for the same task so I started asking around. By the word of mouth, I've learned that the former was originally intended to be the **general** setter of **all** properties but due to technical issues, the functionality was dropped (only retaining the date setting capability due to compatibility issues for pre-existing code).

```
$("#calendar").datetimepicker("update", "weekStart", 4);
```

The above **was but isn't anymore** changing the starting week of the control.

Answer (score 2):

Difference between `bootstrap` datepicker “setDate” and “update” is as follows:

```
$("#calendar").datetimepicker("setDate",new Date()); = triggers an event "change"

$("#calendar").datetimepicker("update",new Date()); = no triggers an event "change"
```

Comment: This is particularly convenient when using external controls like external button for set today, or next/prev day and you need to track this event on datepicker. $('input-group.date').datepicker({}).on('changeDate', function (e) { this will be triggered });  $('.external-set-date-btn').on('click', function (e) { $('input-group.date').datepicker('setDate', new Date()) });